# Node.js Socket.io OO structuring of project Classes

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am having trouble structuring my node.js socket.io project.
Users can join Rooms. A Gameroom has a queue where they can queue for a game. If enough people queue they get thrown into a game lobby. Rooms implement chat functionality which should be used in Gamerooms and Lobbies aswell.

Right now I am passing the io Object to the instantiations and use it to listen to events specific to their class features.

What improvements can I do? Why is this a bad or good design choice? What alternatives are there? What is there to consider?
Should I split  the classes "Room", "Gameroom" and "Lobby" into a more distinct Model & Controller.

I know this is a rather "discussive" question, but I am open for every input. Thanks.

[UML Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Htn74.png)

Server instantiates the Rooms.

```
const io = socket.listen(
    http.createServer(app).listen(8080)
  );

console.log('Server listening..');

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/test.html');
  });

var main = new Room('', io);
var a = new Gameroom('a', io);
var b = new Gameroom('b', io);
```

Room is the parent class, but can also be instantiated. It should be a root channel where everyone joins when they login.

```
class Room {
  constructor(name, io) {
    this.name = name;
    this.users = [];
    this.namespace = io.of('/' + name);
    this.listenOnRoom();
  }

  listenOnRoom() {
    this.namespace.on('connection', (socket) => {
      ...

      socket.on('disconnect', (msg) => {
        ...
      });

      socket.on('chatMessage', (msg) => {
        ...
      });
    });
  }
}
module.exports = Room;
```

Gameroom adds the ability to queue for a game.

```
class Gameroom extends Room {
  constructor(name, io) {
    super(name, io);
    this.io = io;
    this.queue = [];
    this.lobbies = [];
    this.listenOnGameroom();
  }

  listenOnGameroom() {
    this.namespace.on('connection', (socket) => {

      socket.on('userJoinQueue', () => {
        ...
        this.lobbies.push(new Lobby(this.name ,lobbyId, participants, this.io));
      });

      socket.on('userLeaveQueue', () => {
        ...
      });

      socket.on('userLeaveLobby', () => {
        ...
      });
    });
  }
}

module.exports = Gameroom;
```

Lobby is instantiated by the Gameroom when there are enough players in the queue.

```
class Lobby extends Room {
  constructor(gameroom, name, users, io) {
    super(gameroom + '/' + name, io);
    this.users = users;
    this.readyUsers = [];
    this.listenOnLobby();
  }

  listenOnLobby() {
    this.namespace.on('connection', (socket) => {

      socket.on('userReady', () => {
        ...
      });

      socket.on('userUnready', () => {
        ...
      });
    });
  }
}

module.exports = Lobby;
```

Comment: If this code is working and you're looking for ways to improve it, then it probably belongs at http://codereview.stackexchange.com (after you read the posting rules there).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't even know that existed. Yes, it works fine as of right now.